# Rewrite rule for specific name/value to take precedence over others

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L,QSA,B]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewHomepageName&page_identifier=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

I would like to create a new rule to rewrite:

```
/?action=archive&categoryId=$1
```

to

```
/archive/news
```

Where 'news' is the category Id, or $1.

With the two rules mentioned above, is this possible? I would imagine I need to place it above the other rules, and specify specifically if example.com/archive/ rewrite and then stop the rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this in root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# don't process further rules for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(archive)/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=$1&categoryId=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewHomepageName&page_identifier=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava, its working in calling the archive page, but the query on the end isnt working. Any ideas? Could link to the site if it helps?

Comment: as an example adamtoms.co.uk/archive/news, I would expect that to work the same as, ?action=archive&categoryId=news. But its failing and just returning the archive homepage. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Oh sorry that was my mistake, corrected now. Pls check.

Comment: perfect! Thank you so much. Do you mind me asking why it needs the $1 before the &category?

Comment: Because I was trying to avoid repeating `archive` both in pattern and in target and captured it as `$1` and `news` as `$2`

Comment: many thanks, not the first time youve helped me out on here and then explained. Thank you!